# How to add scrollview dynamically in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have created a view which contains an image and a textview (which changes dynamically) and a button. This view is embedded in `UIScrollView`. But when I run it the `Scrollview` is not working. I had this problem in Swift4.

You can refer the link: 
https://github.com/sravyagajavalli/Scrolling

Comment: A full stop is always followed by a capital letter.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @lakshmisravyaGajavalli, this is basic method that are predefine when you create any new `ViewController`, upload your code that you have tried.

Comment: @lakshmisravyaGajavalli pls click on edit below your question to add the code to the question. All additional information should be edited into the question and not added as a comment. Pls. also read [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

It is good to thing about UIScrollView as two separate views. The Frame View (it defines scroll view's size in superview and sibling views) and the Content View (it defines contentSize). In Autolayout point of view are this two views absolutely independent. So you need to define the frameView. And then you need to define autolayout correctly to correct sizing of content View (you do not need to solve the x and y position of course it is matter of contentOffset and scrolling principles). Lets start with example:

1) create UIScrollView add it to superView and define frame View

```
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

2) From my expirience is always good practice to create clear view and add it as contentView into scrollView for better autolayouting.

```
let contentView = UIView()
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
])
```

notice the last constraint, where we need define the width of this content view as equal as screen - this is important to define that we want vertical scroll. Because of this, we can let autolayout do its job and count the scrollView's content height automatically according to content.

3) Add any content what you want into scrollView

```
let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. Maecenas libero. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Duis risus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Integer malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas libero. Nam quis nulla. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Integer in sapien. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Etiam quis quam. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Nullam eget nisl. Mauris metus. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Aliquam id dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Mauris metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. Maecenas libero. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Duis risus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Integer malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas libero. Nam quis nulla. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Integer in sapien. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Etiam quis quam. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Nullam eget nisl. Mauris metus. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Aliquam id dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Mauris metus."
label.numberOfLines = 0
contentView.addSubview(label)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
])
```

**IOS 11 news**

Finally in IOS 11 are new layout guides what solves problems with this frame view and content view in UIScrollView as I mentioned it before.
It is

```
scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
```

so for ios 11 only you can avoid the contentView good practice and do it in this way (but usually we need the backward support for older ios versions)

1) create UIScrollView same as before but define the width with the help of new layout guides

```
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
        ])
```

2) Now just add any content what you want, but attach autolayout into `scrollView.contentLayoutGuide`

```
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. Maecenas libero. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Duis risus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Integer malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas libero. Nam quis nulla. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Integer in sapien. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Etiam quis quam. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Nullam eget nisl. Mauris metus. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Aliquam id dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Mauris metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis sapien nunc, commodo et, interdum suscipit, sollicitudin et, dolor. Maecenas libero. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Nullam at arcu a est sollicitudin euismod. Nullam rhoncus aliquam metus. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Duis risus. Fusce suscipit libero eget elit. Integer malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas libero. Nam quis nulla. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Integer in sapien. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Etiam quis quam. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Nullam eget nisl. Mauris metus. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer rutrum, orci vestibulum ullamcorper ultricies, lacus quam ultricies odio, vitae placerat pede sem sit amet enim. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Aliquam id dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Mauris metus."
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    scrollView.addSubview(label)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

And thats it. You can copy paste both ways into yours viewController viewDidLoad method and it will work.